# Fast and efficient bit scan forward and reset

Tags: gcc, bit-manipulation

I'm using forward bit scan to find out the first set bit after which I reset that bit to 0. Using GCC and 64-bit platform, I've come up with this:

```
uint64_t b = 0, cb = some random arbitrary data

asm("bsfq %0, %0" : "=r" (b) : "0" (cb));

// b now holds the index of first set bit.

cb &= cb - 1; // Reset the first bit.
```

I'm hoping there would be some instruction which would do both at once, but after intensive Googling, haven't found more efficient way to do this. So, is there?

Comment: You mean _more_ efficient than about four instructions? I suspect you won't get much of an improvement :-)

Comment: `bsfq` doesn't exactly look like C++. Is it x86 assembly?

Comment: Yes, x86 assembly. Four instructions is too much, when iterating over billion times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no instruction that both resets the lowest set bit and gets its index. But there are alternatives, some of which may be faster than `bsf\lea\and`.

For example,

```
bsf rax, rdi
btr rdi, rax
```

Helps on Intel (except P4), but on AMD `btr r,r` takes two cycles so it's the same as the latency of `bsf\lea\and`.

Other example,

```
tzcnt rax, rdi
blsr rdi, rdi
```

On Intel, this is not worse (but less widely supported). On AMD this is great, saves a crazy sounding 5 cycles on Jaguar because `bsf` is so slow.